# Controlling DC motor with an Arduino motor shield using PID

Tags: arduino, motor, pid-controller, robot

I'm currently trying to control a DC motor using an Arduino motor shield using PID control. I found this code that can control the motor and also give encoder values and I adapted it for my motor shield. The code is shown below.

Unfortunately the motor isn't moving despite the adaptation but the encoder spits out values when you turn it. I have a schematic of the system. The shield I am using is Ardumoto shield.

I was just wondering if anyone can tell me what the issue is as the hardware has been wired correctly and the code makes sense.

[image: Schematic]

```
    #include <PIDController.h>
volatile long int encoder_pos = 0;
PIDController pos_pid; 
int motor_value = 255;
unsigned int integerValue=0;  // Max value is 65535
char incomingByte;


int dira=12;
int speed_a=3;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  
  pinMode(dira, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(speed_a, OUTPUT);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), encoder, RISING);

  pos_pid.begin();    
  pos_pid.tune(15, 0, 2000);    
  pos_pid.limit(-255, 255);
}

void loop() {

if (Serial.available() > 0) {  
    integerValue = 0;        
    while(1) {           
      incomingByte = Serial.read();
      if (incomingByte == '\n') break;   
      if (incomingByte == -1) continue;  
      integerValue *= 10;  
      integerValue = ((incomingByte - 48) + integerValue);
      pos_pid.setpoint(integerValue);
    }
}

   motor_value = pos_pid.compute(encoder_pos);
if(motor_value > 0){
  MotorCounterClockwise(motor_value);
}else{
  MotorClockwise(abs(motor_value));
}
  Serial.println(encoder_pos);
  delay(1000);
}


void encoder(){

  if(digitalRead(8) == HIGH){
    encoder_pos++;
  }else{
    encoder_pos--;
  }
}

void MotorClockwise(int power){
  if(power > 100){
  digitalWrite(dira, HIGH);
  analogWrite(speed_a, power);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(dira, LOW);
  }
}

void MotorCounterClockwise(int power){
  if(power > 100){
  digitalWrite(dira, LOW);
  analogWrite(speed_a, power);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(dira, LOW);

  }
}
```

Comment: You have two direction pins, and two motors... but the second motor isn't hooked up, so what's the point of trying to control it? And where's the pin that tells the driver to turn on motor A?

Comment: @user253751 I just realised an issue with the code, on this shield it has a PWMA PIN and I just completely neglected it I'm going to add this to the code now. I'm also going to get rid of the pin B code

Comment: Measure the voltage on the bridge input pins.  Measure the voltage on the motor output pins with and without the motor connected.

Comment: @ChrisStratton if the asker is simply using the wrong *control pins*, then the bridge is just fine, and the motor is just fine.

Comment: @user253751 So i edited the code and i just included the speed_a pin which is a PWM pin. I think the problem is the MotorClockwise method.

Comment: Have you tried it? Take out all the PID stuff, and just make it so typing L makes it go left and R makes it go right. Does that work? (make sure the motor isn't attached to anything that would hit you in the face)

Comment: @user253751 the point of measuring control and output voltages is to learn exactly where the problem actually is.  This is basic debugging so it's quite odd to see you taking issue with it, in particular it's important to check *assumptions*.

Comment: @user253751 I was just typing some random numbers in the serial monitor and it worked for a brief second. So, i think that its the motorClock/CounterClockwise methods that are at fault. I need the PID things for the encoder. The encoder works though.

Comment: Always verify every input and output for a valid signal and transfer function. Debug 101